# Unable to upload large Video file in Windows Phone

Tags: video, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am developing an application using Windows Phone 8 which will upload multiple video files on my test server.

I am creating a byte array of each video file generated and using a webservice to upload the video files individually. I am facing an issue that I am only able to upload video files having size upto 100kb data.

Also when I run the code on the emulator it is working fine and uploads the video file but when I deploy the app on windows phone, it is not able to upload file more than 100 kb.

Does the Windows Phone 8 support large data file uploads. (video files having size upto 10MB)?

Following is the code :

```
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URL);
            message.Headers.ExpectContinue = false;
            message.Content = new StringContent(content);
            message.Content.Headers.ContentLength = content.Length;
            if (byt != null)
            {
                message.Content = new ByteArrayContent(byt);
                message.Content.Headers.ContentLength = (byt.Length + content.Length);
            }
            message.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mediaStream);

            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(message);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string StatusText = response.StatusCode + " " + response.ReasonPhrase + Environment.NewLine;
            responseBodyAsText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Can anyone help me out on this.

Regards,

Vijay

Comment: It throws any error messages? I think there is a limitation on the amount of memory the app can handle. But sure it is much more than 100kb.

Comment: @VitorCanova : The code threw 'System.OutOfMemoryException' exception when I uploaded a video of 8MB size.

The same code threw 'Response status code does not indicate success: 404()' exception when I uploaded a 2MB video file.

Comment: Very strange since 404 is `PageNotFound`.

Comment: Ya its strange.. 
404 is not possible as there is a desktop version developed in WPF which is using the same service call for uploading the image.